# Hadoop stdout is always empty and bytes written is zero

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, weka

I am trying to execute Weka on MapReduce and the stdout is always empty

This is the class that runs the whole program. It is responsible
for getting input from the user, setting up the mapper and reducer,
organizing the weka input, etc.

```
public class WekDoop {



     * The main method of this program. 
     * Precondition: arff file is uploaded into HDFS and the correct
     * number of parameters were passed into the JAR file when it was run
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        // Make sure we have the correct number of arguments passed into the program
        if (args.length != 4) {
          System.err.println("Usage: WekDoop <# of splits> <classifier> <input file> <output file>");
          System.exit(1);
        }

        // configure the job using the command line args
        conf.setInt("Run-num.splits", Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        conf.setStrings("Run.classify", args[1]);
        conf.set("io.serializations", "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization," + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");

        // Configure the jobs main class, mapper and reducer
        // TODO: Make the Job name print the name of the currently running classifier
        Job job = new Job(conf, "WekDoop");
        job.setJarByClass(WekDoop.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WekaMap.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WekaReducer.class);

        // Start with 1
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // This section sets the values of the <K2, V2>
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(AggregateableEvaluation.class);

        // Set the input and output directories based on command line args
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[3]));

        // Set the input type of the environment
        // (In this case we are overriding TextInputFormat)
        job.setInputFormatClass(WekaInputFormat.class);

        // wait until the job is complete to exit
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Mapper Class

This class is a mapper for the weka classifiers
It is given a chunk of data and it sets up a classifier to run on that data.
There is a lot of other handling that occurs in the method as well.

```
    public  class WekaMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, AggregateableEvaluation> {
    private Instances randData = null;
    private Classifier cls = null;

    private AggregateableEvaluation eval = null;
    private Classifier clsCopy = null;

    // Run 10 mappers
    private String numMaps = "10";

    // TODO: Make sure this is not hard-coded -- preferably a command line arg
    // Set the classifier
    private String classname = "weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes";
    private int seed = 20;

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        System.out.println("CURRENT LINE: " + line);

        //line = "/home/ubuntu/Workspace/hadoop-1.1.0/hadoop-data/spambase_processed.arff";

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path path = new Path("/home/hduser/very_small_spam.arff");

        // Make sure the file exists...
        if (!fileSystem.exists(path)) {
            System.out.println("File does not exists");
            return;
        }

        JobID test = context.getJobID();
        TaskAttemptID tid = context.getTaskAttemptID();

        // Set up the weka configuration
        Configuration wekaConfig = context.getConfiguration();
        numMaps = wekaConfig.get("Run-num.splits");
        classname = wekaConfig.get("Run.classify");

        String[] splitter = tid.toString().split("_");
        String jobNumber = "";
        int n = 0;

        if (splitter[4].length() > 0) {
            jobNumber = splitter[4].substring(splitter[4].length() - 1);
            n = Integer.parseInt(jobNumber);
        }

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());

        System.out.println("PATH: " + path);

        // Read in the data set
        context.setStatus("Reading in the arff file...");
        readArff(fs, path.toString());
        context.setStatus("Done reading arff! Initializing aggregateable eval...");

        try {
            eval = new AggregateableEvaluation(randData);
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Split the data into two sets: Training set and a testing set
        // this will allow us to use a little bit of data to train the classifier
        // before running the classifier on the rest of the dataset
        Instances trainInstance = randData.trainCV(Integer.parseInt(numMaps), n);
        Instances testInstance = randData.testCV(Integer.parseInt(numMaps), n);

        // Set parameters to be passed to the classifiers
        String[] opts = new String[3];
        if (classname.equals("weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk")) {
            opts[0] = "";
            opts[1] = "-K";
            opts[2] = "1";
        }
        else if (classname.equals("weka.classifiers.trees.J48")) {
            opts[0] = "";
            opts[1] = "-C";
            opts[2] = "0.25";
        }
        else if (classname.equals("weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes")) {
            opts[0] = "";
            opts[1] = "";
            opts[2] = "";
        }
        else {
            opts[0] = "";
            opts[1] = "";
            opts[2] = "";
        }

        // Start setting up the classifier and its various options
        try {
          cls = (Classifier) Utils.forName(Classifier.class, classname, opts);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // These are all used for timing different processes
        long beforeAbstract = 0;
        long beforeBuildClass = 0;
        long afterBuildClass = 0;
        long beforeEvalClass = 0;
        long afterEvalClass = 0;

        try {
            // Create the classifier and record how long it takes to set up 
            context.setStatus("Creating the classifier...");
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            beforeAbstract = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clsCopy = AbstractClassifier.makeCopy(cls);
            beforeBuildClass = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            // Train the classifier on the training set and record how long this takes
            context.setStatus("Training the classifier...");
            clsCopy.buildClassifier(trainInstance);
            afterBuildClass = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            beforeEvalClass = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Run the classifer on the rest of the data set and record its duration as well
            context.setStatus("Evaluating the model...");
            eval.evaluateModel(clsCopy, testInstance);
            afterEvalClass = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            // We are done this iteration!
            context.setStatus("Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Debugging strarts here!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // calculate the total times for each section
        long abstractTime = beforeBuildClass - beforeAbstract;
        long buildTime = afterBuildClass - beforeBuildClass;
        long evalTime = afterEvalClass - beforeEvalClass;

        // Print out the times
        System.out.println("The value of creation time: " + abstractTime);
        System.out.println("The value of Build time: " + buildTime);
        System.out.println("The value of Eval time: " + evalTime);

        context.write(new Text(line), eval);
      }

    /**
     * This can be used to write out the results on HDFS, but it is not essential
     * to the success of this project. If time allows, we can implement it.
     */
      public void writeResult() {    

      }


      /**
       * This method reads in the arff file that is provided to the program.
       * Nothing really special about the way the data is handled.
       * 
       * @param fs
       * @param filePath
       * @throws IOException
       * @throws InterruptedException
       */
      public void readArff(FileSystem fs, String filePath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          BufferedReader reader;
          DataInputStream d;
          ArffReader arff;
          Instance inst;
          Instances data;

          try {
              // Read in the data using a ton of wrappers
              d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(new Path(filePath)));
              reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));
              arff = new ArffReader(reader, 100000);
              data = arff.getStructure();
              data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

              // Add each line to the input stream
              while ((inst = arff.readInstance(data)) != null) {
                  data.add(inst);
              }

              reader.close();

              Random rand = new Random(seed);
              randData = new Instances(data);
              randData.randomize(rand);

              // This is how weka handles the sampling of the data
              // the stratify method splits up the data to cross validate it
              if (randData.classAttribute().isNominal()) {
                  randData.stratify(Integer.parseInt(numMaps));
              }
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Reducer Class

This class is a reducer for the output from the weka classifiers
It is given bunch of cross-validated data chunks from the mappers and its
job is to aggregate the data into one solution.

```
 public  class WekaReducer extends Reducer<Text, AggregateableEvaluation, Text, IntWritable> {
     Text result = new Text();
     Evaluation evalAll = null;
     IntWritable test = new IntWritable();

     AggregateableEvaluation aggEval;

    /**
     * The reducer method takes all the stratified, cross-validated
     * values from the mappers in a list and uses an aggregatable evaluation to consolidate
     * them.
     */
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<AggregateableEvaluation> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {      
        int sum = 0;

        // record how long it takes to run the aggregation
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        long beforeReduceTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // loop through each of the values and "aggregate"
        // which basically means to consolidate the values
        for (AggregateableEvaluation val : values) {
            System.out.println("IN THE REDUCER!");

            // The first time through, give aggEval a value
            if (sum == 0) {
                try {
                    aggEval = val;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                // combine the values
                aggEval.aggregate(val);
            }

            try {
                // This is what is taken from the mapper to be aggregated
                System.out.println("This is the map result");
                System.out.println(aggEval.toMatrixString());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                       

            sum += 1;
        }

        // Here is where the typical weka matrix output is generated
        try {
            System.out.println("This is reduce matrix");
            System.out.println(aggEval.toMatrixString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // calculate the duration of the aggregation
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        long afterReduceTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long reduceTime = afterReduceTime - beforeReduceTime;

        // display the output
        System.out.println("The value of reduce time is: " + reduceTime);
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

And lastly InputFormatClass

Takes a JobContext and returns a list of data split into pieces
 Basically this is a way of handling large data sets. This method allows
 us to split a large data set into smaller chunks to pass across worker nodes
(or in our case, just to make life a little easier and pass the chunks to a single
 node so that it is not overwhelmed by one large data set)

```
    public class WekaInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

    public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job) throws IOException {
        long minSize = Math.max(getFormatMinSplitSize(), getMinSplitSize(job));
        long maxSize = getMaxSplitSize(job);

        List<InputSplit> splits = new ArrayList<InputSplit>();
        for (FileStatus file: listStatus(job)) {
            Path path = file.getPath();
            FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration());

            //number of bytes in this file
            long length = file.getLen();
            BlockLocation[] blkLocations = fs.getFileBlockLocations(file, 0, length);

            // make sure this is actually a valid file
            if(length != 0) {
                // set the number of splits to make. NOTE: the value can be changed to anything
                int count = job.getConfiguration().getInt("Run-num.splits", 1);
                for(int t = 0; t < count; t++) {
                    //split the file and add each chunk to the list
                    splits.add(new FileSplit(path, 0, length, blkLocations[0].getHosts())); 
                }
            }
            else {
                // Create empty array for zero length files
                splits.add(new FileSplit(path, 0, length, new String[0]));
            }
        }
        return splits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the mapper, reducer and overall job, there is an stderr file, an stdout file and a syslog file.

You are printing to stdout in the mapper and the reducer, so you should check the stdout file of the mapper and the reducer not that of the overall job.

Best of luck

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did check in the userlog (localhost:50075/logs/userlogs/job_201504131804_0001) and every mapper has - CURRENT LINE: relation Spambase-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R55-57-weka.filters.unsuperv‌​ised.attribute.NumericToBinary File does not exists CURRENT LINE: File does not exists CURRENT LINE: attribute word_freq_make_binarized {0,1} and reducer stdout is always empty.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. These names seem related to weka with which I'm not very familiar.
But regarding the File Doesn't exist thing, make sure that the path /home/hduser/very_small_spam.arff exists locally on each of the mapper nodes.
The reducer stdout will probably be empty if the mapper failed in the first place

Comment: How to make sure the path exists for each mapper nodes ?

Comment: I mean does this path exist on each of the mapper nodes? or is it just on the master node?

Comment: I dunno much about that.. running this on a single node and the file exists in the given path. But everytime its executing "file does not exists" statement.

Comment: Ah I don't know then. Sorry for that, what you can do though now that you know how to check the stdout is to print everything and everywhere to the stdout and see where it is acting inappropriately

Comment: Got it ! I had to give path as hadoop/input/... .arff . Thank u for guiding me to think in the right direction.